# VBA error when using a dynamic range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to print an empty cell if its adjacent cell has a value. I am using a range from b3 to the last row in the column but  the empty cells there are not checked- the j variable does not get the empty cells. No formulas leaving a space (e.g. " ") are used. Here is the code:

```
 Dim ra as Range
 Dim i as Integer
 Dim cell as Range
 Dim j as String
   i = 0
   Set ra = Range([b3], Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp))
For Each cell In ra     
        If IsEmpty(cell) Then
            If (cell.Offset(1, 0).value <> vbNullString) Then
                j = j & cell.Address(0, 0) & vbNewLine
                i = i + 1
            End If
        End If
Next cell
   ' If i = 0 Then Exit Sub
            msg = msg & vbCrLf & "Sorry, you must enter the missing values in BY Variables sheet in these cells  : " & vbNewLine & j
If msg <> "" Then MsgBox msg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have cells containing formulas that return zero-length strings (e.g. `""`) then they are not considered 'empty'. Only a truly blank cell is True when tested with IsEmpty(cell).

However, both a zero-length string and vbnullstring return True when compared to either a truly blank cell or a cell containing a formula that has returned `""`.

```
For Each cell In ra     
    If cell.value = vbNullString Then
        If cell.Offset(1, 0).value <> vbNullString Then
            j = j & cell.Address(0, 0) & vbNewLine
            i = i + 1
        End If
    End If
Next cell
```

I don't know who is propagating this 'bad practice' syntax,

```
Set ra = Range([b3], Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp))
```

... but it should be abandoned in favor of,

```
with worksheets("sheet1")    'you should know what worksheet you are on
    Set ra = .Range(.cells(3, "B"), .Cells(.Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp))
end with
```

Comment: However, the msg variable again does not return an empty cell with the dynamic range above

Comment: I don't know who has been proselytizing that form of syntax lately but it's just plain 'bad practice'. I've seen it no less than four or five times today. See edit above for 'best practice'.

Comment: The new range is again not checked for an empty cell, if I hardcode it it works but I want to be dynamic

Comment: Do you have formulas leaving a space (e.g. `" "` not `""`)? btw, this is not supposed to be a game of 20 Questions. Please edit your original question to provide an [mcve] so this problem(s) can be resolved with expediency.

Comment: @Hris, what do you mean if you hardcode it, it works, can you give us an example? I believe you are not giving us enough information to facilitate us to give you an appropriate answer to your issue, please be more clear and precise, maybe include images or sample data, so we can visualize what you are trying to say...?

Comment: Range("B3:B18")-with this range it works, otherwise no empty cells are shown:  http://prntscr.com/k1ipcl

Comment: When you say adjacent cell do you mean the next one down (Offset(1,0)) or the next one across (Offset(0,1))?

Comment: @Jeeped - ha, well I just had mine returned, all bright and shiny again.

Comment: I prefer `.Range("b3",. Cells(.Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp)` but I am lazy like that.

Comment: It is ok now, I missed the `row` variable after  `xlup`

Comment: Thanks again for your help :)